# It can have serious complications [to/with/for/on] both mothers and babies

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

Which preposition is the one to use in this sentence?

- It can have serious **complications to** both mothers and babies.
- It can have serious **complications with** both mothers and babies.
- It can have serious **complications for** both mothers and babies.
- It can have serious **complications on** both mothers and babies.

Comment: Only prepositions "on" and "with" seem invalid here; the others are fine. You can have complications with something, not with someone. The most natural option would be "for".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are mixing two different idioms -  to *have* consequences and to *cause* complications.

It can **have** serious **consequences** for both mothers and babies.

or

It can **cause** serious **complications** for both mothers and babies.

In either case, "for" is correct.